# How can I solve this( "Profiling not supported.") in my codesandbox without using node?

Tags: reactjs, redux, profiling

I receive this `Profiling not supported. Profiling support requires either a development or profiling build of React v16.5+.` in my codesandbox, when I want to use the profiler.

I searched about it, and I understood I should run this: `yarn build --profile`

But I'm not finding a terminal in my codesandbox for running that and I should use `node` for having a terminal. But I didn't work with node and server coding, so I'm looking for another solution.

I have access to Profiler on my other project that was made by create-react-app and that use `React-v18.2`. So I changed version of my project on codesandbox to `React-v18.2`. But it still doesn't work.

Please tell me your solution.